# How to display labels above a histogram bin?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I have an array `a(30,2)` where the first column is a unique sample number and the second column is a value assigned to the sample. I plot a histogram of the 2nd column:

```
hist(a(:,2))
```

I have `N` bins and the y-axis tells me how many samples have a value of x,
but no information about which samples are in which bin.

How do I plot, above each bin, a list of samples (the number from the first column of my array `a`) that fall into each bin?

Answer (score 5):

As was shown by both [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657719/how-to-plot-sample-nr-obove-a-histgram-bin/4658257#4658257) and [@Itamar Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657719/how-to-plot-sample-nr-obove-a-histgram-bin/4658032#4658032), the idea is to use HISTC to get the bin indices that each sample belongs to, then use BAR to plot the result (note that we use the `'histc'` mode of display for the BAR function). My answer below is a variation of @Jonas's post:

#### [EDITED]

```
%# random data
a = [(1:30)' rand(30,1)];                %'#

%# compute edges (evenly divide range into bins)
nBins = 10;
edges = linspace(min(a(:,2)), max(a(:,2)), nBins+1);

%# compute center of bins (used as x-coord for labels)
bins = ( edges(1:end-1) + edges(2:end) ) / 2;

%# histc
[counts,binIdx] = histc(a(:,2), edges);
counts(end-1) = sum(counts(end-1:end));  %# combine last two bins
counts(end) = [];                        %# 
binIdx(binIdx==nBins+1) = nBins;         %# also fix the last bin index

%# plot histogram
bar(edges(1:end-1), counts, 'histc')
%#bar(bins, counts, 'hist')              %# same thing
ylabel('Count'), xlabel('Bins')

%# format the axis
set(gca, 'FontSize',9, ...
    'XLim',[edges(1) edges(end)], ...    %# set x-limit to edges
    'YLim',[0 2*max(counts)], ...        %# expand ylimit to accommodate labels
    'XTick',edges, ...                   %# set xticks  on the bin edges
    'XTickLabel',num2str(edges','%.2f')) %'# round to 2-digits

%# add the labels, vertically aligned on top of the bars
hTxt = zeros(nBins,1);                   %# store the handles
for b=1:nBins
    hTxt(b) = text(bins(b), counts(b)+0.25, num2str(a(b==binIdx,1)), ...
        'FontWeight','bold', 'FontSize',8, 'EdgeColor','red', ...
        'VerticalAlignment','bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment','center');
end

%# set the y-limit according to the extent of the text
extnt = cell2mat( get(hTxt,'Extent') );
mx = max( extnt(:,2)+extnt(:,4) );       %# bottom+height
ylim([0 mx]);
```

[image]

If the ticks on the x-axis become too crowded, you can display them rotated with an angle using [XTICKLABEL_ROTATE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate) function (submission on FEX).

Comment: I waited a bit before answering, since I assumed this was right up your alley. And of course you give a nice answer with pretty pictures! One nitpick: `lastEdge` is actually `edges(end)`; you don't need to extract it from the axes limits. +1 anyway for a prettier solution than mine (I like the rectangles), though I'd place the text at counts+0.5.

Comment: @Jonas: thanks for spotting the last-bin bug, I fixed it... I guess its worth mentioning that in the last bin HISTC counts only the values that match `edges(end)` exactly (that's why I combined the last two bins).

Answer (score 4):

First, create a histogram using [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) as suggested by [@Itamar Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657719/how-to-plot-sample-nr-obove-a-histgram-bin/4658032#4658032). To make the bins the same as with [HIST](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html), you need to properly calculate bin edges. Then you can plot the distribution and add the labels using [TEXT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) and [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html).

```
%# get the edges, bin centers
nBins = 10;
edges = linspace(min(a(:,2),max(a(:,2),nBins+1); %# edges go from minimum to maximum of distribution
bins = (edges(1:end-1)+edges(2:end))/2;

%# get the counts and the bin-index
[counts,binIdx] = histc(a(:,2),edges);

%# plot the counts and bins (not edges) with `bar`
figure
bar(bins,counts);

%# Set the axes limits such that you have enough space for the labels
ylim([0,2*max(counts)]);

%# add the labels. Vertically align such that the text goes from the y-coordinate
%# down (as opposed to being centered on the y-coordinate).
for b = 1:nBins
    text(bins(b),counts(b)*2,num2str(a(b==binIdx,1)),'VerticalAlignment','top')
end
```

Comment: +1 exactly what I was thinking, I posted another solution based on your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `histc`, which return an index for each entry, to which bin did it 'fall':

> [n, bin] = histc (a(:, 2), bins);

Then the samples above the k'th bin is:

> a(bin==k, 1);

Pay attention, you must specify the bins' boundaries yourself (unlike `hist` which uses the mid-value between boundaries).