# Bar plot with labels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

How can I simply add vertical labels of the current value to [bar plot](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) in Matlab?

I want to add the current value where now "here" is:

[image]

Comment: you'd have to create text graphic objects, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4657719/97160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [question I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4657719/97160) to in the comments is one way to do it. There are other ways to customize bar plots, for instance see [this article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/bar-plot-customizations) (although starting with HG2, the internals have changed considerably, so it got a trickier to reach inside and retrieve the data we need).

If you're willing to dig deep, here is a solution that should work with MATLAB R2014b and newer (note that I'm using undocumented properties to get the hidden "Face" graphic objects created by the bar plot):

```
Y = rand(3,4);
h = bar(Y);
drawnow   % this is needed for some reason!

opts = {'VerticalAlign','middle', 'HorizontalAlign','left', ...
    'FontSize',8, 'Rotation',90};
for i=1:numel(h)
    clr = h(i).Face.ColorData(1:3);
    vd = h(i).Face.VertexData;
    xy = double(vd(1:2,2:4:end) + vd(1:2,4:4:end)) / 2;
    for j=1:size(xy,2)
        text(xy(1,j), xy(2,j), sprintf(' %.2g',xy(2,j)), ...
            'Color','k', opts{:})
    end
end
```

[image: barplot]