# How can I show the legend to all bars in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

Below in the figure, I am trying to show the legend to all bars, but I only get the legend for the first bar. How can I show it to all of them?

[image]

```
figure
CoverageArea = [101.1303,0,114.9316,45.2112,116.5973,95.8953];
BarNames = {'\Phi_1_/_2 = 15, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 10','\Phi_1_/_2 = 15, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 40','\Phi_1_/_2 = 30, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 10','\Phi_1_/_2 = 30, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 40','\Phi_1_/_2 = 60, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 10','\Phi_1_/_2 = 60, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 40'};
h = bar(CoverageArea,'stacked');
ylabel('Coverage area (m²)');
xticklabels({'\Phi_1_/_2 = 15, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 10','\Phi_1_/_2 = 15, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 40','\Phi_1_/_2 = 30, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 10','\Phi_1_/_2 = 30, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 40','\Phi_1_/_2 = 60, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 10','\Phi_1_/_2 = 60, (\phi & \psi) =\pm 40'})
colors = get(gca(), 'ColorOrder' ); % use whatever colors you want here
set(h, 'FaceColor' , 'flat' , 'CData' ,colors(1:6,:)) % set the bars' colors
hLg = legend(BarNames,'Location','best');
grid on;
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082486/how-to-add-legend-on-a-bar-chart Its slight different, but I believe that is what you need to do, i.e. plot bars 1 by 1.

Comment: But the reason why this is not trivially supported is because you are literally just repeating the data from the x-labels. The entire point of the X-labels is that you don't use legend I guess. Its generally a bad idea to add repeated/superfluous information to a scientific plot, as its distracting.

Comment: I very strongly agree with @Ander. You should not be doing this. There cannot be a single benefit to a legend for each individual bar. You might as well just do a table instead.

Comment: One thing you see a lot in business graphics, but you should also really not do, is write the plotted value on the top of each bar. You should not do this because you’re doing something redundant, you’re showing the same data in two ways. If exact values are needed, use a table. But if you really want to do that, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250780/7328782